# Difference between `is-agent?` and `is-turtle?`

Tags: netlogo

I believe this must be an easy question, but I have not found the difference between `is-agent?` and `is-turtle?` primitives, and when I should use one instead of the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turtles, patches, and links are all agents.  So `is-agent?` will return `true` for any of those.  But patches and links are obviously not turtles, so `is-turtle?` will return `false` for those.

```
breed [ ghouls ghoul ]

to test
  clear-all
  create-turtles 1
  create-ghouls 1
  ask turtle 0 [ create-link-to turtle 1 ]

  show is-agent? turtle 0   ; true
  show is-agent? ghoul 1    ; true
  show is-agent? patch 0 0  ; true
  show is-agent? link 0 1   ; true

  show is-turtle? turtle 0  ; true
  show is-turtle? ghoul 1   ; true
  show is-turtle? patch 0 0 ; false
  show is-turtle? link 0 1  ; false

  show is-ghoul? turtle 0   ; false
  show is-ghoul? turtle 1   ; true
end
```

So if you're trying to differentiate agents from things like numbers, strings, and true/false values, you'd use `is-agent?`.  When you really, for-sure want to be dealing with turtles, use `is-turtle?`.

Comment: A new breed then it will be an agent but not a turtle?.

Comment: Updated the answer with breeds example - each breeded turtle is *also* a turtle, so `is-turtle? ghoul 1` does give `true`.